# I reverted a file to origin but when i do pull request it still shows under files changed?

Tags: git

I accidentally made changes to a file and pushed to my branch on remote and made a pull request, upon seeing files changed I realize there is a file I shouldn't have comitted.

I reverted changes in the file using this command.

```
git checkout origin/master filename
```

File shows as modified in git status. So I commit and push, but file stills shows as modified in pull request. Although my changes aren't there.

Thinking maybe origin changed while I did pull I did git pull but it's all up to date.

Comment: Which OS are you using? It might be the line ending issue. Whenever you commit from Windows/Linux/MacOS it uses different line endings: CRLF (windows) or LF(linux based OSs)

Comment: I am on linux through docker